# Image wont repeat on Mobile

Tags: html, css

Background-repeat doesn't work in mobile browsers. Atleast, it doesn't do anything when I try to browse the content in a mobile browser. Is there any size differences?

Here is the css

```
#header {
    background: url(images/header_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
     ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work i think:

```
#header {
    background: url("images/header_bg.png") repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);

    /* Give a height and width*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35dre/

Edit: Also you don't need to specify moz, webkit, ms (box-shadow) anymore.